# Передача файла на TCP сервер(не могу разобраться почему код не работает)

Tags: c#, .net

Привет всем, изучаю сетевое программирование на различных примерах, что нашел в инете. Так вот нашел пример в котором автор отправляет файлы с клиента на сервер.
TCP сервер:

```
class Program
{
    private static Thread thrDownload;

    private static Stream strLocal;

    private static NetworkStream strRemote;

    private static TcpListener tlsServer;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server has started");
        thrDownload = new Thread(StartReceiving);
        thrDownload.Start();
    }

    private static void StartReceiving()  
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ipadress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8005);

            if (tlsServer == null)
            {
                tlsServer = new TcpListener(ipadress);
            }

            tlsServer.Start();

            TcpClient tclServer = tlsServer.AcceptTcpClient();


            strRemote = tclServer.GetStream();


            int bytesSize = 0;


            byte[] downBuffer = new byte[2048];

            bytesSize = strRemote.Read(downBuffer, 0, 2048);

            string FileName_full = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
            string FileName = GetFileName(FileName_full);
            strLocal = new FileStream(@"C:\"+ FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            Console.WriteLine(">" + @"C:\" + FileName);

            downBuffer = new byte[2048];

            bytesSize = strRemote.Read(downBuffer, 0, 2048);
            string Filesize_full = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
            long FileSize = GetFileSize(Filesize_full);


            downBuffer = new byte[2048];

            while ((bytesSize = strRemote.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                strLocal.Write(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
            }
        }
        finally
        {

            strLocal.Close();
            strRemote.Close();

            StartReceiving();
        }
    }

    public static void ViewIPAdress(byte[] b)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < b.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.Write(b[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static string GetFileName(string str)
    {
        List<string> list = str.Split('&').ToList();
        string name = list[0];
        return name;
    }

    public static long GetFileSize(string str)
    {
        List<string> list = str.Split('&').ToList();
        long size = Convert.ToInt64(list[1]);
        return size;
    }
}
```

TCP клиент:

```
class Program
{
    private static TcpClient tcp_client;

    private static FileStream fs_stream;

    private static NetworkStream ntw_stream;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConnectToServer("127.0.0.1", 8005);
        Console.Write("Select file fo sending> ");
        string file_path = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending file information...");
        ntw_stream = tcp_client.GetStream();
        byte[] byteSend = new byte[tcp_client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        fs_stream = new FileStream(file_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader bnr_reader = new BinaryReader(fs_stream);
        FileInfo inf = new FileInfo(file_path);

        string File_name = inf.Name + "&";
        byte[] byte_Filename = new byte[2048];
        byte_Filename = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(File_name.ToCharArray());
        ntw_stream.Write(byte_Filename, 0, byte_Filename.Length);

        string file_size = inf.Length + "&";
        byte[] byte_filesize = new byte[2048];
        byte_filesize = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(file_size.ToCharArray());
        ntw_stream.Write(byte_filesize, 0, byte_filesize.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("Sending the file " + File_name + " (" + file_size + " bytes)\r\n");

        int ByteSize = 0;
        byte[] Downbuffer = new byte[2048];

        while((ByteSize = fs_stream.Read(Downbuffer,0,Downbuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ntw_stream.Write(Downbuffer, 0, ByteSize);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("File sent. Closing streams and connections.\r\n");
        tcp_client.Close();
        ntw_stream.Close();
        fs_stream.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Streams and connections are now closed. \r\n");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ConnectToServer(string ServerIP, int ServerPort)
    {
        tcp_client = new TcpClient();
        try
        {
            tcp_client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), ServerPort);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to server\r\n");


        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Суть проблемы:
Спокойно подпключаюсь к серверу и указываю какой файл передать. Но проблема появляется на строках получения имени файла и размера файла на сервере. У меня допустимый размер буфера 2048, соответственно оно по потоку бросает все, что поместиться(имя файла + размер файла + текст файла). По этому я в клиенте добавил к названию файла и его размеру разделитель '&', а на сервере делаю сплит, чтобы достать имя файла и размер файла на сервере. Я смог таким оброзом с первой передачи достать имя файла, но с размером файла не вышло, так как строка полученная из потока обрезана(в ней нету начала). В общем я скорей всего не понимаю как правильно работать с потоковой передачей из-за чего немогу исправить даную ошибку, помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

> У меня допустимый размер буфера 2048, соответственно оно по потоку бросает все, что поместиться(имя файла + размер файла + текст файла).

Судя по всему, ошибка в этом предположении.

TCP — потоковый протокол, в нём данные не обязательно доходят кусками, соответствующими отправленным кускам. Вы должны передавать длину сообщения, и потом вычитывать байты из потока до тех пор, пока всё сообщение не дойдёт (для это понадобится цикл).

Чтение должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
byte[] ReadExact(Stream s, int nbytes)
{
    var buf = new byte[nbytes];
    var readpos = 0;
    while (readpos < nbytes)
        readpos += s.Read(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos);
    return buf;
}
```

```
var nbytes = BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadExact(strRemote, 4), 0);
var data = ReadExact(strRemote, nbytes);
```

Ну и на отправляющей стороне нужно не забыть передать длину.

Answer (score 1):

Я просто исправил но это не оптимальный код.

1. Неправильная конвертация в пустом массиве.
2. Неправильная отправление информации по TCP.

(то есть отправляешь два три пакета и не можешь соединить)

это Server.

```
class Program
{
    private static Thread thrDownload;

    //private static Stream strLocal;

    private static NetworkStream strRemote;

    private static TcpListener tlsServer;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server has started");
        thrDownload = new Thread(StartReceiving);
        thrDownload.Start();
        thrDownload.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("Server has stopped");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void StartReceiving()
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ipadress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8005);

            if (tlsServer == null)
            {
                tlsServer = new TcpListener(ipadress);
            }
            tlsServer.Start();

            TcpClient tclServer = tlsServer.AcceptTcpClient();
            strRemote = tclServer.GetStream();



            List<byte> Bytes = new List<byte>();
            Bytes.WholeAdding(strRemote);
            ReceivedFile Model = ConvertFileModel(Bytes.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("FileName : {0}\nFileSize : {1}\nFileContent : {2}",Model.FileName,Model.FileSize,Model.FileContent);

        }
        finally
        {

            strRemote.Close();

            StartReceiving();
        }
    }


    private static ReceivedFile ConvertFileModel(byte[] DBytes)
    {
        try
        {

            string FullData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(DBytes);
            ReceivedFile File = new ReceivedFile();
            int FinishedIndex;
            File.FileName = GetSelected(FullData, 0, '&',out FinishedIndex);
            File.FileSize = GetSelected(FullData, FinishedIndex+1, '&', out FinishedIndex);
            File.FileContent = FullData.Substring(FinishedIndex+1);
            return File;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
    }


    private static string GetSelected(string Data,int Started, char Finished,out int FinishedIndex)
    {

        for (int i = Started; i < Data.Length; i++)
        {

            if (Data[i].Equals(Finished))
            {
                FinishedIndex = i;
                string Sub = Data.Substring(Started, (i - Started));
                return Sub;
            }
        }
        FinishedIndex = -1;
        return null;
    }




}
```

это Client.

```
class Program
{
    private static TcpClient tcp_client;

    private static FileStream fs_stream;

    private static NetworkStream ntw_stream;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConnectToServer("127.0.0.1", 8005);
        Console.Write("Select file fo sending> ");
        string file_path = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending file information...");
        ntw_stream = tcp_client.GetStream();

        fs_stream = new FileStream(file_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader bnr_reader = new BinaryReader(fs_stream);
        FileInfo inf = new FileInfo(file_path);



        string HeaderData = string.Format("{0}&{1}&", inf.Name, inf.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n\n",HeaderData);

        List<byte> Bytes = new List<byte>();
        Bytes.WholeAdding(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HeaderData)));
        Bytes.WholeAdding(fs_stream);
        byte[] DBytes = Bytes.ToArray();
        ntw_stream.Write(DBytes, 0, DBytes.Length);



        Console.WriteLine("File sent. Closing streams and connections.\r\n");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        tcp_client.Close();
        ntw_stream.Close();
        fs_stream.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Streams and connections are now closed. \r\n");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }



    private static void ConnectToServer(string ServerIP, int ServerPort)
    {
        tcp_client = new TcpClient();
        try
        {
            tcp_client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), ServerPort);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to server\r\n");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

это Helper Method.(Extension)

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void WholeAdding(this List<byte> Bytes, Stream Str)
    {
        int Data = -1;
        while ((Data = Str.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            if (Data == -1)
                break;
            Bytes.Add((byte)Data);
        }
    }
}
```

это File Model.

```
public class ReceivedFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string FileSize { get; set; }

    public string FileContent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Это на каком языке написано? У нас русскоязычный сайт!

Comment: @PavelMayorov очень Быстрее написал извиняюсь . изменил.