# Преобразование массива байтов в строку, затем обратно и в файл

Tags: c#, wpf, кодировка, unicode, base64

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, пишу мессенджер на WPF C# с сервером на C#.
Передаю массив байтов на сервер, допустим для авторизации, таким образом:

```
Send($"#authorization|{login}|{password}");

_serverSocket.Send(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(buffer));
```

И на сервере могу спокойно получить строку с логином и паролем

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
```

Проблема в том, что для получения изображения подходит только Base64 с конвертацией в BitmapImage.

Есть ли какие-то другие кодировки, которые смогут отправлять и текст сообщения и байты файлов или придется писать два разных метода отправки?

Comment: «_Проблема в том, что для получения изображения подходит только Base64_» — а почему это вдруг? Вангую, ваша проблема не в этом, а в том, что вы не передаёте длину массива байт, вот ваша картинка и приходит не полностью. Разница со строкой — размер, картинка гораздо больше. Посмотрите примеры тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648960/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/772159/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/713354/10105

Comment: `Проблема в том, что для получения изображения подходит только Base64` нет, не в том.