# Получение пакета данных NetworkStream C#

Tags: c#, .net, сеть, tcp, tcpclient

Есть проблема в получении данных по TCP/IP. При соединении Хост отправляет данные размером 32 байта один раз в 500мс, в нем организован так же буфер, который при проблемах со связью накапливается и при появлении оной, начинает снова отправлять пакеты по сети. Для их получения я использую на клиенте TcpClient и NetworkStream. Я написал следующий код:

```
 public byte[] ReadData()
    {
        var receivedData = new byte[BufferSize]; 

            try
            {
                tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = ReceiveTimeout;
                var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                var receivedBytes = stream.Read(receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length);
                return receivedData;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.ErrorMessage("Ошибка чтения: ", e);
            }

            throw new ApplicationException("Ошибка чтения или подключения к хосту!");
    }
```

Использование:

```
            while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var data = client.ReadData();
                _dbContext.Save(Guid.NewGuid, data);
            }
```

В управляющем коде, после открытия хоста в бесконечном цикле вызывается данный метод. Все работает прекрасно, пока не происходят проблемы с сетью. Из-за того что на хосте есть накапливаемый буфер, после возобновления связи он начинает выплевывать данные, но теряется последовательность пакета. Как правильно обработать и накопить "правильные" 32 байта данных? В них нет никаких сплиттеров, разграничителей и банальных старт-стоп байт. В теории, читать бы это все по байтово (может binary reader и складывать в массив каждый байт?) и как только размер будет 32 - считаем, что пакет пришел правильный.
UPDATE 15.06.2021
Измененный метод, с добавлением метода из ответа @VladD

```
 public void ReadData()
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
                var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

                var receivedBytes = BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadExact(stream, ReceivedBufferSize), 0);
                var receivedData = ReadExact(stream, receivedBytes); // Отсюда уже не выходит....

                ReceivedDataEvent?.Invoke(new DataReceivedEventArgs(receivedData));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.ErrorMessage("Ошибка чтения: ", e);
                CloseConnection();
            }
        } while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    }
```

Comment: Вам нужна процедура `ReadExact` отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/713354/10105. `stream.Read` не гарантирует, что он доставит вам в точности полный буфер

Comment: Не ясно одно из данного примера, хост у меня не отправляет в пакете длину, но я знаю, что пакет ровно из 32 байт...

Comment: Ну так вызывайте `ReadExact(tcpClient.GetStream(), 32)`

Comment: Благодарю! Буду пробовать!

Comment: Попробовал данный способ, и у меня есть проблема. Никогда не выходит из цикла вашего метода почему-то. Т.е позиция постоянно инкрементируется. Думаю из-за того, что данные идут потоком непрерывно.

Comment: Хм, странно, а покажите ваш код?

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: Смотрите, вам не нужно `var receivedBytes = BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadExact(stream, ReceivedBufferSize), 0);`, потому что сервер не посылает размер, а посылает по 32 байта пакеты фиксированного размера.

Comment: Просто уберите получение `receivedBytes`, и впишите `var receivedData = ReadExact(stream, 32);`

Comment: Снова вопрос. Странное поведение, не могу понять. При старте приложения, используя ваш код первые 4 -5 итераций данные приходят корректные. Дальше почему-то последние 2 байта всегда приходят одни и те же. Если в методе ReadExac сделать `readPosition += stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);` То работает корректно...

Comment: Это очень странно. А покажите ваш код, может, ошибка где-то ещё.

Comment: Код не изменял, как указан в вопросе. Еще один нюанс, бывает, что пакеты пропадают. Если нагружать процессор фоновыми задачами.

Comment: Очень странно. А не может быть такого, что у вас одновременно два потока читают из одного соединения?

Comment: Может быть проблема, что в цикле бесконечном вызывается var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

Comment: Да не должно по идее. Хотя, почему бы и нет, попробуйте получить Stream в переменную за циклом